# Doctrine ODM set namespace for documents

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces, doctrine, doctrine-odm

How I can set namespace where Document classes are in Doctrine ODM? For example I have:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Documents\Users;     

class User {
    ...
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace Application\Documents\Books;

class Book {
    ...
}
```

I want to setup Doctrine so I can type just

```
public function getUserByID($userID) {
    return $this->manager->find('Users\User', $userID);
}
```

instead of `Application\Documents\Users\User` or `Books\Book` instead of `Application\Documents\Books\Book` inside `find()`. In other words I wanna setup Doctrine so that it adds `Application\Documents\` before every document path.

Can it be done? How? Thanx